# Views is stripping tags from the output

Tags: drupal, content-management-system, tags, drupal-views

I have a Drupal view which should output a video player using flash. I am trying to output a script that will call the flash film. The problem is that Views applies some sort of filter that strips my `<script>` tags, the opening and the closing one. I am searching a solution (some setting in views that will disable that filter), but cannot seem to find an answer. Other HTML tags work, but it seems the script tag is being stripped, probably for some security reason.

I have selected the option to rewrite the output of the field and I am using the tags correctly

Views also strips style attributes from my tags. For example:

```
<h3 style="border-bottom: solid 1px #ffcc99;">Some text here</h3>
```

appears like this:

```
<h3>Some text here</h3>
```

Is there a solution for this? Thank you.

---

Begin edited

---

I am pasting below the code I am using in my view.

```
<div class="bloco-filme">
  [title]
  <div class="field-imagem">
    [field_imagem_fid]

    <script type='text/javascript' src='sites/default/files/js/swfobject.js'></script>

    <div id='mediaspace[nid]'>Se você estiver visualizando esta mensagem, significa o Flash Player não está instalado em sua máquina. Para assistir ao vídeo é preciso instalar o Flash player</div>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
      var so = new SWFObject('sites/default/files/plugins/jqplayer/player.swf','mpl','205','undefined','9');
      so.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');
      so.addParam('allowscriptaccess','always');
      so.addParam('wmode','transparent');
      so.addVariable('file','[field_video_fid]');
      so.addVariable('quality','false');
      so.write('mediaspace[nid]');
    </script>
    [field_video_fid]
  </div>
  <div class="field-resumo">
    <p>[body]</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Edited again

---

The code above is beinng posted in my view. I have created a view to handle this. This is the FIELDS area of my view:

Fields
Node: Nid
Node: Título (title, it is in pt-br)
Node: Link "editar" (edit)
Node: Link "apagar" (delete)
Conteúdo: Imagem thumbnail image
Conteúdo: Video URL do arquivo (video file URL)
Node: Corpo (Body)

I have disabled the display of all the fields above and have packed all the code in the Body field. There I selected the option that I want to rewrite the output of the field.

Comment: What is the video? Is it an embedded youtube video? If so where is it embedded? Does it use a player hosted on your site like Wimpy? Is it a video file uploaded to a CCK file field? Are you pasting HTML into a node which is supposed to display the video, and if not how are the videos uploaded / displayed? If they are uploaded to the nodes do they show when viewing the node directly?

Comment: Hi, it is a flv file. I am using JWPlayer. I am using javascript code to embed it (swfobject.swf) as suggested here: http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player-setup-wizard. The video was uploaded through a CCK file field. In the video field I am requesting its raw URL and then I am rewriting the output to use the script to pull the video using its raw URL. When viewing the nodes directly the videos are shown as links to download, that is the default theming for the file field with a download link.

Comment: "In the video field I am requesting its raw URL and then I am rewriting the output to use the script" - Where are you processing this? In a custom mod?

Comment: No, I have created a view. I am editing my post to add exactly the content of my view in there...

Comment: Maybe I'm being thick - but what do you mean that's the content of your view? Where have you entered that code?

Comment: Hi, I have just paseted the code above. I have created a view. I am querying all my "video" content types. I have selected to show the title, the body, the image (file uploaded) and the video (file uploaded) fields. If it is not clear, I will explain again. Thanks.

Comment: maybe this discussion is of help: http://groups.drupal.org/node/77518

Comment: Hi, Raoul, it probably has to do with a filter being applied. But... in my view, how can I completely turn off the filter? How can I get rid of it in the output of my view? I want a full output. There isn't such an option in the view configuration.

Comment: Where are you pasting the code above exactly?

Comment: When you define a view, you can set an header, or the content to show when a view is empty; you don't define the content of a view with the code you reported.

Comment: I am editing again my post above to show you that info...

Comment: kiamlaluno, please, read the reviewed post. I am explaining where the code was placed. I have rewritten the output of one of my fields.

Comment: OK, so your code is in the body field of the node? At last I think I understand. Forgive me if I still don't understand correctly, but do you need to paste that code into every body field for a node you upload a video to? Why not do something like create a small module which rewrites the (video) CCK field on any node of that content type to use the code you need to display the video?

Comment: Hi, yes, you got it right. I have pasted the code inside the output of one of the fields, the body field. I have never written a module myself because, I can be simple, isn't it? I thought it would be more work to write a module (since I am not familiar with it) than using a view. But since the view has all these problems...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

kiamlaluno identified the basic problem, but to solve it, you're going to have to use a field template which will avoid using the filtering system Views uses. [Group 42 has a great guide](http://www.group42.ca/theming_views_2_the_basics) to walk you through the basics of Views theming, so I'll just gloss over those details and talk about your specific case.

First, you need to identify which field you want to rewrite: I believe you're doing that using the Field configuration, but it's not clear which field you are rewriting. I'm going to assume it's the body field. Go through Group 42's guide to create a new template file for the body field in your theme.

In the new template file, use the following code:

```
<div class="bloco-filme">
  <?php print $view->field['title']->render($row) ?>
  <div class="field-imagem">
    <?php print $view->field['field_imagem_fid']->render($row) ?>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='sites/default/files/js/swfobject.js'></script>

    <div id="mediaspace<?php print $view->field['nid']->render($row) ?>">Se você estiver visualizando esta mensagem, significa o Flash Player não está instalado em sua máquina. Para assistir ao vídeo é preciso instalar o Flash player</div>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
      var so = new SWFObject('sites/default/files/plugins/jqplayer/player.swf','mpl','205','undefined','9');
      so.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');
      so.addParam('allowscriptaccess','always');
      so.addParam('wmode','transparent');
      so.addVariable('file','<?php print $view->field["field_video_fid"]->render($row) ?>');
      so.addVariable('quality','false');
      so.write('mediaspace<?php print $view->field["nid"]->render($row) ?>');
    </script>
    <?php print $view->field['field_video_fid']->render($row) ?>
  </div>
  <div class="field-resumo">
    <p><?php print $output ?></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Save your new template file, and now the body field will be replaced with the correct output. Just make sure all the fields you've referenced in the template are before the body field within the *Fields* list when you edit the *View*.

You can see that this is mostly HTML with a few PHP bits. Code like this:

```
<?php print $view->field['title']->render($row) ?>
```

outputs the contents of a field other than current one (i.e. you use this code when you want to reference fields other than Body). It references the same row and finds the value of the field.

And code like this:

```
<?php print $output ?>
```

Outputs the value of the current field, in this case, Body.

Comment: Hi, Mark, thank you so much, that was a great advice, I am completely in the right track now!! The only problem I face now is that when I get the raw data for my file fields, all I can get is the ID of the files. Instead of the URL (the processed output of my fields), I am probably getting the raw data. What I would like is the $output of the image and the video fields. Do you have any ideas how can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that; `$row` returns the raw output. I've edited my answer to use `$view->field['field_name']->render($row)`, which will output the rendered contents.

Comment: Hi, Mark, thank you. I have solved everything. In the end, I decided to use views-view-fields which seemed to me as a slightly better approach. I had never had the patience to really go over the documentation of views theming. It is very iteresting. Although I have spent some hours on this today, it will probably be very useful in the future.

Comment: No problem: view-view-fields is definitely the better choice if you want to rewrite the entire row.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the view is causing the issue. kiamlaluno is quite correct that the input format will strip a lot out of your code, unless you alter the input format, however I'm not sure you'll actually be able to achieve what you are trying to do using the body field in any sort of graceful way.

Use views to output the content you need from each node type, but I never use views to determine how this will be displayed (apart from ordering fields etc). I tend to do this either using the display fields option (/admin/content/node-type/[your-node-type]/display) or in the theme. In other words I theme the node (content type) or the field itself.

I would consider looking here - http://drupal.org/node/206980 - to see how to theme individual fields. use the field_ (field name prefix) at the start of a copy of the content-field.tpl.php in your theme folder (you'll find it in the theme folder of your cck folder), and use this to theme the field the way you want it to be presented (using your code above). So, when the view picks it up to display it, it will theme it using your code above.

This, of course, has the added advantage that you don't need to add in any code to the body element of the page, which is not a scalable way to do this at all.

Alternatively, you could [write a small module](http://drupal.org/node/231276) which uses hook_field() ([link 1](http://drupal.org/node/206980), [link 2](http://drupal.org/node/342996)) to rewrite the field display, but unless you want to be able to customize any of this in the admin area of the site, your best option is probably to theme the field itself as above.

Answer (score 0):

I had nearly exactly this issue (thanks for posting it!), but a few things have changed (obviously) in the three years since this post.

In my case, using Views 3 and D7, I was able to paste all of the relevant swfobject code into a Header or Footer of my view, making sure to use the Text Area type with Full HTML as the text input filter.

No editing of the template.php was necessary. I even used token replacement to provide contextual filter arguments to my movie's flashvars.